# MySql PHP syntax retrieve ordered data, some with matching values and shuffle/randomize the matching values only

Tags: php, mysql, random

Finding it difficult to get my head around the mysql syntax to retrieve data from a database - the data has a 'rating' and needs to be ordered from the highest rating down to the lowest.

If there is a matching rating number between two or more rows I need to be able to randomize these rows but retain them in the overall order of the list.

Basically I have a table of 'agents', a table of 'agent_coverage' by postcode, and a 'rating' table containing a numeric rating. To pseudo code it I need to :-

1.select agent_id, rating from agent, rating, agent_coverage where agent_coverage.postcode = postcode and rating.agent_id = agent_id GROUP BY rating.rating ORDER BY rating.rating DESC

1. I then need to check if there are more than one result in the group
2. If there are more than one in the group I need to shuffle the group and return the data in the order highest to lowest.

so if BOB had a rating of 100, JOE, SYLVIA, FRED and BARBARA all had a rating of 98 and RICHARD had a rating of 96, BOB would always be number one in the returned results - RICHARD would always be last in the results but the other position would be randomized each time.

Hope thats a bit clearer.

Comment: A little code/script/schema could be of help to answer.

Comment: concrete example, please. what exactly do you want to randomize? the order of the columns, or do you want to only select one of those with the same rating? why is the order done by mysql (more or less random for same rating value) not enough?

Comment: updated ther question a slight bit although it is the coding that I am having problems with.

Comment: Show us the code you got so far.